# efficient grid lookup by coordinate in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to implement a simple grid lookup in Tcl.  You can think of the grid items as boxes within a grid.  Something like the following.

[image: Grid Image]
I have the x and y coordinates of the boundaries (left, right , top bottom) of each of the blue boxes within the coordinate space shown in a dictionary called boxcoordinates

given an arbitrary X and Y point, what is the most efficient way to identify which (if any) of the blue boxes are intercepted by the X,Y pair?

I'm currently doing a check for each box, on the conditions where Left < X < Right and Bottom < Y < Top to see which box satisfies those conditions.

Something like

```
foreach boxid [dict keys boxcoordinates] {
  if {([dict get $boxcoordinates $boxid LEFT] < $x) && ([dict get $boxcoordinates $boxid RIGHT] > $x) && ([dict get $boxcoordinates $boxid BOTTOM] < $y) && ([dict get $boxcoordinates $boxid TOP] > $y)} {
    set selected $boxid
    break
  }
}
```

But that seems very inefficient since there are a lot of boxes to scan through.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are these displayed in a canvas?

Comment: @Brad Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by a canvas.  These boxes are spread out out on a coordinate plane with some arbitrary spaces in between.

Comment: Is this a regular grid of boxes? Are the boxes all the same size? The more regularity, the cheaper the search algorithm can be.

Comment: @Donal in this example, I showed them as regularly spaced and the same size for simplicity of explanation, but in the actual application, they are irregularly spaced and of different sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort the coordinate list in a regular fashion, you can do a binary search to find the coordinates you are looking for.  The example below only has 9 entries, but should give you the idea.  The coordinates used in this exampled are ordered as x1, x2, y1, y2.

```
global vars

proc init { } {
  global vars

  set vars(d) {
    0 {1 4 1 4}
    1 {1 4 6 8}
    2 {1 4 10 12}
    3 {6 8 1 4}
    4 {6 8 6 8}
    5 {6 8 10 12}
    6 {10 12 1 4}
    7 {10 12 6 8}
    8 {10 12 10 12}
  }
}

proc lCompare { a b } {
  lassign $a ax1 ax2 ay1 ay2
  lassign $b bx1 bx2 by1 by2

  if { $bx1 < $ax1 } {
    return -1
  } elseif { $bx2 > $ax2 } {
    return 1
  } elseif { $by1 < $ay1 } {
    return -1
  } elseif { $by2 > $ay2 } {
    return 1
  }
  return 0
}

proc bsearch { mx my } {
  global vars

  set target [list $mx $mx $my $my]
  set low 0
  set high [expr {[dict size $vars(d)]-1}]
  while { $low <= $high } {
    set mid [expr {($low+$high)/2}] ; # integer division
    set lrc [lCompare [dict get $vars(d) $mid] $target]
    if { $lrc > 0 } {
      set low [expr {$mid+1}]
    } elseif { $lrc < 0 } {
      set high [expr {$mid-1}]
    } else {
      return $mid
    }
  }

  return -1
}

init
set idx [bsearch 3 10]
puts "A:$idx"
set idx [bsearch 10 10]
puts "B:$idx"
set idx [bsearch 3 3]
puts "C:$idx"
set idx [bsearch 5 9]
puts "D:$idx"
```

Output:

```
bll-tecra:bll$ tclsh z.tcl
A:2 
B:8 
C:0
D:-1
```

References: [wikipedia: Binary Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)